# get datakey value and label text from Datalist on click of button?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0, datalist

how to get the value of Datakey and lable which is present inside datalist?

i have a image button and linkbutton on click of them i am trying to get but i am unable to do.
i don't want to use Item_Command event.

How to do?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem when in Command event and why you don't want to use?

Comment: There is no problem but i am trying to get through imageClick event and linkClick event. Is it possible?? if yes then please guide me.

Comment: You can get DataKey Value but you can't get label text if you have more items in DataList

Comment: @Muhammad: So you mean to say i can only datakey value on click of linkbutton?? in listview we can get value from lables inside the listview on click of linkbutton or button.

Comment: If you need to both value, you can bind both value to CommandArgument, e.g. CommandArgument="34,labelText" and then split this value. But I would recommend you to only bind Data Key value to Command Argument. once you have primary key value, you can the entity detail from DB.

Comment: actually i can't be hitting the database if i can keep two hidden field and store the value. Actually with those two value and primary key i have to make URL. I am using asp.net 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to Get the `Data Key` value on the Click of the `ImageButton/LinkButton`, you can set the DataKey value to the `CommandArgument` property of your control and then in the Click handler you can get the value from the `CommandArgument` property.

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ibtn" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("DataKeyName")%>'
 ImageUrl="~/Images/edit.png"></asp:ImageButton>
```

Same case for linkbutton as well.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the button click event, you can do the following to get the DataKey and the Label (assuming it's in the same control collection as the button):

```
var button = sender as Button;

if (button == null) return;

var dataListItem = button.NamingContainer as DataListItem;

if (dataListItem == null) return;

var currentKey = DataList1.DataKeys[dataListItem.ItemIndex];

var myLabel = button.Parent.Controls.Cast<Control>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == "testLabel") as Label;

if (myLabel == null) return;

var myLabelText = myLabel.Text;
```